# How to use value of a function in another function of same class

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

```
class test():
    def abc():
        a = 5;
        b = 6;
        c = 7;
        return a,b,c
    def defg():
        print('inside defg second function')
        a,b,c = abc()
        return a,b,c
```

when I try to access it   a = test() ,a.abc()

TypeError: abc() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: Try to use `def abc(self):` and `def defg(self):`.[Read it in official document](https://docs.python.org/zh-cn/3/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Test():
    def abc(self):
        a = 5
        b = 6
        c = 7
        return a,b,c
    def defg(self):
        print('inside defg second function')
        a,b,c = self.abc()
        return a,b,c

c = Test()
c.defg()
```

First of all, all class methods [must have](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) `self` first parameter.
Second, you need to use `self.` in one method if you want to call another method of your object. And finally, it is better to call your classes from capital letter.

Otherwise you cane use [static methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) in your class if your code don't work with instance variables:

```
class Test():
    @staticmethod
    def abc():
        a = 5
        b = 6
        c = 7
        return a,b,c
    @staticmethod
    def defg():
        print('inside defg second function')
        a,b,c = Test.abc()
        return a,b,c

c = Test()
c.defg()
```